# Не рабтает валидация в Spring через @Valid

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

У меня есть класс Customer:

```
package ru.dmko.entities;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Customer {

    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, message = "is required")
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Есть customerController:

```
package ru.dmko;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import ru.dmko.entities.Customer;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @RequestMapping("/page")
    public String customerPage(Model model) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
        return "customerPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/process")
    public String processCustomerPage(@Valid @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer,
                                      BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "customerPage";
        }
        return "processPage";
    }

}
```

Также 2 jsp странички, customerPage:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Customer page</title>
    <style>
        .error{
            color : red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Customer page</h1>
    <a href="">main page</a>
    <form:form action="process" modelAttribute="customer">
        first name: <form:input path="firstName"/>
        last name: <form:input path="lastName"/>
        <form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

processPage:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Process page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Process page</h1>
    <a href="page">customer page</a>
    Customer name: ${customer.firstName} ${customer.lastName}
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-di</artifactId>
        <groupId>ru.dmko</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>valid-spring-mvc</artifactId>

    <name>valid-spring-mvc</name>
    <description>my valid spring mvc project</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге я хочу увидеть валидацию на поле lastName, но если оно у меня не заполнено, то валидация все равно не происходит, не могу понять в чем проблема, ошибок тоже никаких нет, просто происходит переходит на страницу с выводом имени cusotmera. Все это делпою на Tomcat

Если lastName не заполнен, то должно появится фраза указанная в классе Customer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что делаю не так? может быть как то не так описываю тег form:errors в jsp.

Comment: Для понимания требуется валидатор применять и возвращать уже не тагом

Comment: @RomanC не совсем понял, что имеешь ввиду